# Entity Framework One to One navigation property not loading

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So I have a simple database with two tables setup with code first using entity framework 6.02.  The Submission table has a one to one relationship with the tbl_lst_Company table.  They are related by the company and CompanyID fields.

```
public partial class Submission
{
    public Submission()
    {           
        this.Company = new tbl_lst_Company();
    }
    public int Keytbl { get; set; }
    public int companyid { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_lst_Company Company { get; set; }        
}

public partial class tbl_lst_Company
{       
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
}
```

And here are the Fluent mappings:

```
    public SubmissionMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Keytbl);
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Submissions");
        this.Property(t => t.Keytbl).HasColumnName("Keytbl");
        this.Property(t => t.companyid).HasColumnName("company");

        this.HasRequired(q => q.Company).
        WithOptional().Map(t => t.MapKey("Company"));
    }

    public tbl_lst_CompanyMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.CompanyID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Company)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("tbl_lst_Company");
        this.Property(t => t.CompanyID).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
        this.Property(t => t.Company).HasColumnName("Company");
    }
```

Here is my unit test I am running to test the above implementation:

```
    public void download_data() {
        var db = new SubmissionContext();
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        var subs = (from s in db.Submissions                     
                    select s).Take(100);
        var x = subs.First().Company;
        var a = subs.ToArray();            
    }
```

My problem is that the Company field is always null when I run this test.  If I explicilty say from s in db.Submissions.Include("Company"), then the Company field is not null but I have to eager load the navigation property.  I want the Company navigation property to lazy load.  As far as I can tell I am doing everything the way it is suppose to be done but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is the `Company` really `null` or is it an uninitialized object? I see that you instantiate the navigation property in the `Submission` constructor (`this.Company = new tbl_lst_Company();`) which is not good. You should remove this line in any case. However, I'm not sure if it will solve your particular problem here.

Comment: The actual Company class is not null, but once expanded, all the properties within it are null.

Comment: Taking out the instantiation of Company, throws this error when view thing Company variable with the debugger: '(a[0]).Company' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException'

Comment: Are there inner exceptions that tell more details about this EntityCommandExecutionException? What about the `x` in your example? Is it the expected company or null or do you get an exception on that line as well?

Comment: Thanks, I think i figured it out.  Indeed, instantiation a single navigation property causes the item to be always null with lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out, there were a number of things wrong, but here is the solution that worked for me.  You do not need to instantiate a single navigation property.  This will cause it to be always null.  You still need to instantiate the navigation property if it is an ICollection of objects.  There were a few other minor things as well. Thanks for the help.

```
public partial class Submission
{       
    public int Keytbl { get; set; }
    public int Company { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_lst_Company tbl_lst_Company{ get; set; }        
}

public partial class tbl_lst_Company
{       
public tbl_lst_Company() {
        this.Submissions = new List<Submission>();
}
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
}

public tbl_lst_CompanyMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.CompanyID);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.Company)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(150);
    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("tbl_lst_Company");
    this.Property(t => t.CompanyID).HasColumnName("CompanyID");
    this.Property(t => t.Company).HasColumnName("Company");
}

public SubmissionMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.Keytbl);
    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Submissions");
    this.Property(t => t.Keytbl).HasColumnName("Keytbl");
    this.Property(t => t.Company).HasColumnName("Company");

    this.HasOptional(t => t.tbl_lst_Company)
    .WithMany(t => t.Submissions)
.HasForeignKey(d => d.Company);
}

[TestMethod]
public void test_lazy_loading() {
    using (var db = new SubmissionContext()) {
    var subs = (from s in b.Submissions                     
                   select s);
    var x = subs.First().tbl_lst_Company;
    Assert.AreEqual(x, null, "Lazy Loading Failed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want `x` populated but you don't want to populate the company of every single submission in `a`.

You can tell it to load the company of the first one, *then* use it.

```
var first = subs.First();
first.CompanyReference.Load();
var x = first.Company;
var a = subs.ToArray();
```

Comment: I would like it to load the Company reference via lazy loading. As I understand lazy loading, whenever that variable is accessed ,it should load it.  At this point I would be happy with it loading every single company within submission if I could get it to work without using the Include option to eagerly load it.

Comment: Are you sure that document is not outdated, it is from 2008?   Everything else I have read says you don't need to use Load.  I think that example is explicitly loading:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx