# EF Code First DbContext returns encapsulated entity only for first element of collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

Very strange behaviour from EF which has me pulling my hair out.

The problem pertains mainly to the following entity class, and it's encapsulated properties:

```
public class ContextParamValue
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public Int64 ContextParamId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContextParam ContextParam { get; set; }

    public virtual ContextInstance ContextInstance { get; set; }

    public Int64 ContextInstanceId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I have a ContextParamValue class, which has a unidirectional 1 to 1 relationship with ContextParam. Thus, ContextParamValue can access ContextParam but not the other way around.

The piece of code that has me in tatters are as follows:

```
public List<ContextParamValue> ParamValuesToList(string[] ParamNames, string[] ParamValues)
{
    if (ParamNames != null && ParamNames.Length != ParamValues.Length)
        throw new System.ArgumentException("ParamNames and ParamValues may not differ in length.");

    List<ContextParamValue> rList = new List<ContextParamValue>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ParamNames.Length; i++)
    {
        string pName = ParamNames[i];
        string pValue = ParamValues[i];

        List<ContextParamValue> lst = db.ContextParamValues
            //.Include(x => x.ContextParam)
            .Where(pv => pv.ContextParam.Name.ToLower().Trim().Equals(pName.ToLower().Trim()))
            .Where(pv => pv.Value.Equals(pValue))
            .ToList<ContextParamValue>();

        rList.AddRange(lst);
    }

    return rList;
}
```

The strange result of this code is that `ContextParam` is only loaded for the first element returned in `rList`.  All the subsequent elements in `rList` has a null value for the `ContextParam` property.  The following screenshots shows the element instance values during debugging:

[image: First element in the list is A-OK]
***First element in the collection... WINNING!***

[image: Subsequent elements... HUGE FAIL]
***Second element in the collection... MASSIVE FAIL!***

I have tried multiple alternative implementations for the above method, namely lazy loading, eager loading, even not building up the list from within a loop (I constructed a dictionary of the `ParamNames` and `ParamValues` array objects which allowed me to do set-based matching within the LINQ expression). Same result every time.

I also include the relevant snippets from my `DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ModelMapper.InitializeRelationshipMappings(modelBuilder);
    base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
}
```

AND

```
public static class ModelMapper
{
    public static void InitializeRelationshipMappings(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.FileItem)
            .WithOptional(fi => fi.Document)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);


        modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
            .HasMany(d => d.DocumentClasses)
            .WithMany(dc => dc.Documents);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContextClass>()
            .HasMany(cc => cc.RequiredClasses);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContextClass>()
           .HasMany(cc => cc.OptionalClasses);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContextClass>()
            .HasMany(cc => cc.Params)
            .WithRequired(cp => cp.ContextClass)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContextInstance>()
            .HasRequired(ci => ci.ContextClass);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContextInstance>()
            .HasMany(ci => ci.ContextParamValues)
            .WithRequired(cpv => cpv.ContextInstance)
            .HasForeignKey(cpv => cpv.ContextInstanceId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContextParamValue>()
            .HasRequired(cpv => cpv.ContextParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason ContextParam is absent from the mapping?

Comment: Ummm... it's not missing... the very last statement in the last code snippet above reads: modelBuilder.Entity<ContextParamValue>()
            .HasRequired(cpv => cpv.ContextParam);

Comment: This seem related then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916947/entity-framework-one-to-one-navigation-property-not-loading

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately not though.

Comment: @WiktorZychla perhaps I should rather ask this: in which way do you suspect it to be related?

Comment: since it is one to one mapping why is it returning a list? another thing which you can try is

List<ContextParamValue> lst = new List<ContextParamValue>();

  lst = db.ContextParamValues
            .Include(x => x.ContextParam)
            .Where(pv => pv.ContextParam.Name.ToLower().Trim().Equals(pName.ToLower().Trim()))
            .Where(pv => pv.Value.Equals(pValue))
            .ToList<ContextParamValue>();

Comment: I was also wondering that is type casting at the end .ToList<ContextParamValue>(); is creating problem can you try with var?

Comment: Have you debugged the "for loop" and watched to see what happened to the ContextParam Property during the second iteration of the loop?  Is it populated with information from the db? I am curious if the names and values are only matching for the first item and not matching for the rest of the items. One other question: Because you are casting to a list, can we assume that there are instances where there are multiple objects returned with the same name and value? Or was that done for ease of writing the code, and only one object will ever be returned?

Comment: I'm also thinking along the same lines as @JohnBartels.  Debug through that loop and take a look at what you find in `lst` on each iteration.      Also take note of what the values of `pName` and `pValue` are.  Another thing that concerns me is, where is `db` declared?  It appears to be of `private` scope or wider, which immediately sets off some warning flags, though that may not be connected, but still I'd be interested to see what happens if you put all this code inside a `using` block and be sure to eager-load `ContextParam`.

Comment: @John Bartels.  I am not sure that I completely understand your first remark/question correctly.  The values I am passing in should match for the rest of the items.  If it does not match a specific record then that record should not be returned in the result list.  The answer to your second question is that there can be multiple matches (same name and value) that should be returned.

Comment: @Shaul This method is member of a "helper" class, which has it's own DbContext member.  The class has a DbContext parameter in its constructor which sets the value of the DbContext member.  The class is instantiated by an ASP.Net MVC controller, which passes its already instantiated DbContext into the constructor.

Comment: @AnshulNigam Not sure if I used the appropriate terminology, but the relationship is 1-to-1 in one direction.  From Param to ParamValue the logical relationship (which was not hard coded) is one-to-many.

Comment: Firstly, assumption is the mother of all f**kups; debug the forloop eh... and secondly are you sure your implementation of DBContext is thread safe?

Comment: @SirJuice Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703059/strange-null-reference-exception-in-linq-query-with-ef?lq=1

Comment: @Paul Zahra Thanks for the link - but I actually posed that question and it is the same issue.  The post you linked to actually just provides a workaround for the issue but does not identify and address its root cause (which I am looking for in this thread).

Comment: @SirJuice ah lol didn't notice it was you that asked that question lol... anyhow in my experience issues akin to this and the other question are often due to shared contexts, hence I believe why others have suggested using a 'using' statement; in effect using a new context a la 'unit of work'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if it is not a data related issue.
2. Else try replacing your code

   ```
      List<ContextParamValue> lst = db.ContextParamValues
       //.Include(x => x.ContextParam)
       .Where(pv => pv.ContextParam.Name.ToLower().Trim().Equals(pName.ToLower().Trim()))
       .Where(pv => pv.Value.Equals(pValue))
       .ToList<ContextParamValue>();

   rList.AddRange(lst);
   ```

with another LINQ

```
List<ContextParamValue> lst = from db.ContextParamValues.Where(pv => pv.ContextParam.Name.ToLower() == pName.ToLower().Trim()
                          && db.ContextParamValues.Where(pv => pv.Value == pValue)).ToList<ContextParamValue>();
```

- This might be a context issue as it is either not able to load or not able to execute the linq.Try commenting your code & I am sure you can use SP to get this data (I did the same & it worked)

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I can confirm it is definitely not a data-related issue, there are no null references in any of the referenced tables.  ContextParam.Name is of type string and so is ContextParamValue.Value, therefore the Equals operator should work fine.  Apart from that the query you wrote above is basically just the LINQ query I wrote translated into query syntax.  I have found a temporary workaround but I am specifically trying to establish what the root cause of this issue is.

Comment: I am interested in your comment about this possibly being a context-related issue (you are the only person who have brought this up thus far) and I would like to explore that a bit further.  What exactly do you mean with "context issue"?

Comment: Actually Shaul also mentioned this earlier.  Sorry @Shaul!

Comment: @Sir Juice, Can you please show your Work Around, just curious how you u accomplished without SQL Injection...

Comment: Sure, the workaround is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703059/strange-null-reference-exception-in-linq-query-with-ef

Answer (score 0):

Humour me, please.  Put your whole `for` loop inside a `using` block:

```
using (var myDb = new MyDataContext()) 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < ParamNames.Length; i++)
   { 
     //etc., replacing "db" with "myDb" 
   }
}
```

I would be interested to know if this changes anything.