# Strange null reference exception in LINQ query with EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**I have the following three related entity classes:**

```
public class ContextInstance
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ContextParamValue> ContextParamValues { get; set; }
}

public class ContextParamValue
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Int64 ContextParamId { get; set; }

    public virtual ContextParam ContextParam { get; set; }

    public virtual ContextInstance ContextInstance { get; set; }

    public virtual Int64 ContextInstanceId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ContextParam
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**I have set up fluent relationships as follows:**

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

modelBuilder.Entity<ContextInstance>()
                .HasMany(ci => ci.ContextParamValues)
                .WithRequired(cpv => cpv.ContextInstance)
                .HasForeignKey(cpv => cpv.ContextInstanceId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

**I have the following "Helper" class, the ParamValueToList method of which is intermittently throwing a *null-reference exception*:**

```
public class RuntimeHelper : IDisposable
    {
        DocumentDbContext db;

        ConfigurationHelper ch;

        private RuntimeHelper()
        {
        }

        public RuntimeHelper(DocumentDbContext context)
        {
            db = context;
            ch = new ConfigurationHelper(context);
        }

        public List<ContextParamValue> ParamValuesToList(string[] ParamNames, string[] ParamValues)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("-- ParamValuesToList invoked --");

            if (ParamNames != null && ParamNames.Length != ParamValues.Length)
                throw new System.ArgumentException("ParamNames and ParamValues may not differ in length.");

            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ParamNames.Length; i++)
            {
                string pName = ParamNames[i];
                string pValue = ParamValues[i];
                d.Add(pName, pValue);
                Trace.TraceInformation("ParamValuesToList Key: " + pName + "; Value: " + pValue + ";");
            }

            Trace.TraceInformation("Value of db:" + db.ContextParamValues.ToString());

            var cpvList = db.ContextParamValues
                 .Include(x => x.ContextParam)
                 .ToArray<ContextParamValue>();

            List<ContextParamValue> lst = cpvList
                 .Where(pv => d.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pv.ContextParam.Name, pv.Value)))
                 //.Where(pv => true == true)
                 .ToList<ContextParamValue>();

            Trace.TraceInformation("-- ParamValuesToList executed --");

            return lst;
        }

        public List<ContextInstance> GetContextInstances(List<ContextParamValue> ContextParamValues, bool AsNoTracking = false)
        {
            if (!AsNoTracking)
                return db.ContextInstances
                    .Include(x => x.ContextClass)
                    .Include(x => x.ContextParamValues.Select(p => p.ContextParam))
                    .Include(x => x.Documents)
                    .AsEnumerable<ContextInstance>() // <-- Allows boolean method as part of LINQ query
                    .Where(ci => IsSubset(ci.ContextParamValues, ContextParamValues))
                    .ToList<ContextInstance>();
            else
                return db.ContextInstances
                    .Include(x => x.ContextClass)
                    .Include(x => x.ContextParamValues.Select(p => p.ContextParam))
                    .Include(x => x.Documents)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .AsEnumerable<ContextInstance>()// <-- Allows boolean method as part of LINQ query
                    .Where(ci => IsSubset(ci.ContextParamValues, ContextParamValues))
                    .ToList<ContextInstance>();
        }

        public List<ContextInstance> GetContextInstances(string[] ParamNames, string[] ParamValues, bool AsNoTracking = false)
        {

            return GetContextInstances(ParamValuesToList(ParamNames, ParamValues), AsNoTracking);
        }
}
```

The specific statement from the above method that is throwing the error is

```
List<ContextParamValue> lst = cpvList
                 .Where(pv => d.Contains(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(pv.ContextParam.Name, pv.Value)))
                 .ToList<ContextParamValue>();
```

**The null reference exception is *NOT* thrown under the following condition:**

- There exist, for a given ContextInstance, only 1 ContextParamValue
- Example, ContextParamValue.ContextParam.Name = "ClientId" and ContextParamValue1.Value = "1"

**The null reference exception *is* thrown under the following condition:**

- There exist, for a given ContextInstance, two-or-more ContextParamValues
- Example, ContextParamValue1.ContextParam.Name = "ClientId" and ContextParamValue1.Value = "1" PLUS ContextParamValue2.ContextParam.Name = "MotivationId" and ContextParamValue2.Value = "1".

**I can confirm the following about the helper method in question:**

- d is not null nor does it contain any keyvaluepairs with null values
- cpvList is not null and not empty when the error occurs.
- ContextParam does not load for parent ContextParamValue entities in all cases (it only loads for the first ContextParamValue instance but for subsequent instances only a null value is loaded).
- There are no null ContextParam entries in database... All ContextParamValues has one ContextParam entry.

**The following *trace* and *stacktrace* information is generated during runtime:**

> Application: 2014-05-16T19:00:20 PID[4800] Error
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.  Application: at
>   DocumentManagement.Helpers.RuntimeHelper.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__27(ContextParamValue
>   pv) in c:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\xxx\Active
>   Projects\xxx\DocumentManagement\Helpers\DocsHelper_RT.cs:line 229
>   Application: at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator1.MoveNext() 
>   Application:    at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1
>   collection)   Application:    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
>   Application: at
>   DocumentManagement.Helpers.RuntimeHelper.ParamValuesToList(String[]
>   ParamNames, String[] ParamValues) in c:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\xxx\Active
>   Projects\xxx\DocumentManagement\Helpers\DocsHelper_RT.cs:line 228
>   Application: at
>   DocumentManagement.Helpers.RuntimeHelper.GetContextInstances(String[]
>   ParamNames, String[] ParamValues, Boolean AsNoTracking) in
>   c:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\xxx\Active
>   Projects\xxx\DocumentManagement\Helpers\DocsHelper_RT.cs:line 262
>   Application: at xxx.Controllers.ClientController.LoadStep2(Int64
>   ClientId, String Error) in c:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\xxx\Active
>   Projects\xxx\xxx\Views\Client\ClientController.cs:line 198

[image]

[image]

Comment: if "lst" is not null, doesn't that mean that your first query succeeded? If it threw an exception, "lst" wouldn't have been assigned in the first place. You enumerate the query by calling ToList() on it, so the query will either be executed successfully with "lst" assigned, or throw an exception, leaving "lst" unassigned.

Comment: For debugging, i suggest you put your predicate from the Where clause in a separate method (let's call it "predicate") and change the Where clause into `.Where(predicate)`. Put an exception handler in your predicate method that allows you to set a breakpoint which will be triggered when an exception occurs - this will help you diagnosing where you have a null value. Because, one thing seems to be certain based on your explanation: The Linq query seems to resolve a null reference somewhere...

Comment: @Pawel - Done.  Updated my question with the stacktrace information.

Comment: @elgonzo - Could you perhaps provide an example, I am not quite following.  Also, this is happening on a live test environment that is hosted on Azure - not sure whether it is relevant or not.

Comment: What do you mean with "live test environment"? Does it mean you cannot use a debugger?

Comment: I can do remote debugging (it is very slow, however), and I have to publish any changes made to Azure first.  I can not, however, recreate the error on my local environment (just take this statement on face value) without considerable effort.

Comment: Well, for starters... There is no Linq to Entities here.  cpvList is actually an Array, and d is a Dictionary.  No EF in that query at all.

Comment: @SirJuice, [let's continue in chat...](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53849/discussion-between-elgonzo-and-sir-juice)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Ah, yes, sorry about that.  It started out as LINQ-to-EF but I changed it while trying to fix the issue.

Comment: I have now also created an issue on the Entity Framework codeplex project page to try and identify and resolve the issue.  https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2282

Comment: @SirJuice - This is not a bug in EF, so reporting it as an issue with them will likely lead to nothing.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Maybe, I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way that your code would throw an exception would be if pv.ContextParam were null, because that is the only place you are dereferencing something that might cause a null pointer exception.

This would happen if you have ContextParamValues records without a corresponding ContextParam record, thus ContextParam would be null.  Since we can't see your data model, you will have to check for that.

Add this line of code and check in the debugger to see if it's true:

```
bool containsNulls = db.ContextParamValues
    .Include(x => x.ContextParam)
    .Any(x => x.ContextParam == null)
```

EDIT (removed all the middle steps, check history if you're interested):

Well, this doesn't actually answer the question, but it would solve your problem.  Let's just rewrite your code to be simpler and more efficient.  If I read your code right, all you're looking to do is return the ContextInstances that have associated ContextValueParams with the provided name/value pairs, correct?

Why not just do this (add includes as you see fit):

```
public List<ContextInstance> GetContextInstances(
       string[] ParamNames, string[] ParamValues, bool AsNoTracking = false)
{
    var p = ParamNames.Zip(ParamValues, (a,b) => a+b);

    var ctx = db.ContextInstances
       .Where(x => p.All(y => x.ContextParamValues
          .Select(z => z.ContextParam.Name + z.Value).Contains(y)));

    return (AsNoTracking ? ctx.AsNoTracking() : ctx).ToList();
}
```